# Menu from array and creating html

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array of menus. It has title, depth, mlid(menu id ) and plid(parent id). I want to create html structure for eg like this

```
               <li class="has-children">
                <a href="#?p=409">Accessories</a>

                <ul class="is-hidden">
                    <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Clothing</a></li>
                    <li class="see-all"><a href="#?p=409">All Accessories</a></li>
                    <li class="has-children">
                        <a href="#0">Beanies</a>

                        <ul class="is-hidden">
                            <li class="go-back"><a href="#0">Accessories</a></li>
                            <li class="see-all"><a href="#?p=409">All Benies</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#?p=409">Caps &amp; Hats</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#?p=409">Gifts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#?p=409">Scarves &amp; Snoods</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#?p=409">Glasses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#?p=409">Gloves</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#?p=409">Jewellery</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#?p=409">Scarves</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#?p=409">Wallets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#?p=409">Watches</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

My menu in cms is like this [image]

Currently in cms. It is coming like this in
$menu

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array        
        (
            [name] => Accessories
            [depth] => 1
            [mlid] => 353
            [plid] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Beanies
            [depth] => 2
            [mlid] => 354
            [plid] => 353
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Gifts
            [depth] => 3
            [mlid] => 355
            [plid] => 354
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Caps
            [depth] => 3
            [mlid] => 357
            [plid] => 354
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Scarves
            [depth] => 3
            [mlid] => 356
            [plid] => 354
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => Glasses
            [depth] => 2
            [mlid] => 358
            [plid] => 353
        )

)
```

I'm lost how to write code that either make this menu to direct html structure or into a child like array according to tree hierarchy(so i could go and make html from that). Thank you.

Comment: So, you expect someone to write a code for you? Okay

Comment: @u_mulder i'm looking for some hints. I'm kind of lost.

Comment: Check `depth` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Use foreach loop and inside it write your html code.

```
foreach ($ menu as $ v => $ r) 
{
       <"Your html code here">
}
```

Hope this suffice.